# MySQL completely uninstalled and reinstall but database still exists on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, reinstall

I need to completely remove MySQL all databases and installation and reinstall, because root is broken. I followed this instructions:

```sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

But when I install again with

```sh
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Old databases, old users table with broken users, etc.. are here, so it doesn't completely uninstall/repair.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /etc/mysql*
```

before the `install` to delete everything, but be careful you can have third parties schemas there like phpmyadmin,... So consider deleting one by one subfolder.

Maybe there is an elegant way of doing this, like `mysql_secure_installation`

Comment: In my case doing this lead me to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626974/error-while-installing-mysql.

Comment: YEs, but don't forget to purge it first `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`